# export generated table to excel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, excel

User interface of my web app is

[image]

First user selects country,city ,year and month. Based on this selection user clicks the display button. On clicking the display button it loads some javascript code  which is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function tbl_display(){
     var sel_countryid= $("sel_country").val();
          var sel_cityid= $("#sel_city").val();
          var dataString = 'sel_countryid='+ sel_countryid+ '&sel_cityid='+ sel_cityid;  
         alert(dataString);
          if(sel_regionid=='' || sel_lbtype=='')
              {

                  alert("Please enter Valid Data");
              }
           else
           {
                $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "tbl_create.php",
              data: dataString,
              cache: true,
              success: function(html){
                      $("#result_table").html(html);
              }

              });

           }   

         } 
    </script>
```

In tbl_create.php page I have done  sql query and echo the table .

when user clicks on this export button this table have to be exported to excel. My question is can I use the same query or I have to do another query to generate excel file

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to google it u will find lot of code for exporting mysql to excel   [link](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2038-PHP-Export-data-from-a-MySQL-database-to-Excel-files.html)

Comment: @sasikanth I googled it and found many references. But my query is Should i have to requery to generate excel file or can I use same query for exporting ?

Comment: u need to call a page there u need to write the query then do export...see above comment u will find a link there you can find the code

Comment: You need write an other sql query and its export functionality to excel

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same query to generate the Excel file. You can use php excel. Here is the link: [PHP Excel Library](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For optimization purposes, it is recommended to use the same query results.
Check the PHP code sample from this link:

http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/export-list-to-excel.html

It uses [EasyXLS Excel library](http://www.easyxls.com) for exporting to Excel.